# Create Property files in grails and display content in main.gsp layout

Tags: file, grails, properties, gsp

How and where to create property file in grails and i have to display the content of property file in main.gsp(Layout)

Comment: I want to display title from property file in main.gsp page.so my property file have title string.Can i use message.properties for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store message in `grails-app/i18n/messages.properties` and use `g:message` tag, like:

```
<g:message code="my.message.code" />
```

See docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html